# How to increase deletion speed of several folder

Tags: linux, rhel5, rm

I have a script containing about 420k lines of "rm -rf" command like which where generated using a "find" statement. Each **pdf**'s folder is containing between 1 and 30 files (no subfolder).

```
rm -rf /2012/128/211503/pdf
rm -rf /2012/128/212897/pdf
rm -rf /2012/128/211989/pdf
rm -rf /2012/128/211691/pdf
rm -rf /2012/128/212539/pdf
rm -rf /2012/218/358976/pdf
rm -rf /2012/218/358275/pdf
rm -rf /2012/218/358699/pdf
```

I'm searching how to increase the deletion speed of the script.

Currently, **vmstat** report only about (IO) wait time.

Platform is RHEL 5 deleting files on a RAID5/6 drive using ext3 and LVM.

I thought about splitting the script file into smaller files (like 10 files) in order to trigger several script in parallel but here I'm spotting a hardware speed limitation.

Would that be a good idea if the commitment of the deletion for the journalization taking time and could it take part of feature like NCQ ?

Comment: You can use find to delete files it will be faster then first generate script with find and then run the script that actualy deletes the files

Comment: @B14D3 You could probably make a real answer of that, with a little expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to generate the script you should take a look at the `-delete` action

> Delete files; true if removal succeeded. If the removal failed, an error message is issued. If -delete fails, find's exit status will be nonzero (when it eventually exits). Use of -delete automatically turns on the -depth option

You could use [split](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split) to break up the file into chunks. You may get some milage out of [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) too.

Comment: If fact, we are using find to generate the script to check that the list of folder is not containing unwanted items. We know how to **split** the files into smaller chunks but thanks for advice. Here GNU Parallel doesn't seem to be relevant. Question was more about hints to reduce each command execution time as a group like if there as some commitment in the OS regarding the deletion of one files.

Comment: Like one deletion taking 1sec to delete at the disk and 1 sec to commit at the ext3 journal `so to delete 5 files one after another one it would take (1+1)*5 = 10 sec` but in parallel mode like in UC execution pipes two files at the same time would lead to `1 sec for IO first file then 1 sec for commitment of the first file while also taking 1 sec for the IO of the second file then 1 sec for commitment of the second file so here taking only 3sec for two files.` We were wondering if it would be relevant to use and if gain would just be negligible or even worst due to concurrent access.

Comment: @TheCodeKiller: Group lots of files onto the same rm command line/